# How to access class attributes within a class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to reference a class attribute from class variable but it gives me error `'self is not defined'`

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    data = self.val

    def main(self):
        print(self.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `data = self.val` outside `__init__`, you are defining a class variable, not an instance variable. This line affects all objects of type Test. However, self is not recognized in this scope.

If you want `val` to update all instances of this class,

```
class Test:
    data = None
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        Test.data = self.val
```

In this case,

```
test1 = Test(1)
print(test1.data) # prints 1
print(Test.data)  # prints 1
test2 = Test(2)
print(test1.data) # prints 2
print(test2.data) # prints 2
print(Test.data)  # prints 2
```